# Unable to select all faces

Tags: edit-mode

Hey pretty new to blender and im trying to make some skins for csgo guns, I want to have certain parts of the gun have one material and other parts have other materials. In edit mode it wont let me select all faces so I cant add it all to an material, sorry if that badly explained screenshots are below.
is there any way to fix this
[image]

[image]

Comment: Nevermind, face select words fine edge select wont for some reason